# Redux manipulate state object

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux, state-management

My target is to add element of mapped array into redux object. Example:
List of Students json

```
[
    {id: "1", name: "Anie"},
    {id: "2", name: "John"}
]
```

In Redux I have:

```
const initialState = {
  students: []
}
const students = (state = initialState, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case 'ALL_STUDENTS':
      return Object.assign({}, state, {
        students: action.students
      })
    }
}
```

My target is data to look like that:

```
[
    {someprop: "", student: {id: "1", name: "Anie"}},
    {someprop: "", student: {id: "2", name: "John"}}
]
```

I need add user object as a prop of person object in Object assign. How is that possible. Which is most correct way to do that?

Comment: currently you have one reducer for students. do you want another reducer for persons?

Comment: no need persons array. Just need to change students array

Comment: If they're students you don't need the `student` property in the student object. I think you're uneccessarily over-complicating your dataset.

Comment: This is what I want to do

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `map()` method on passed list of students to add new property to each object inside and then use spread syntax in object and array to add those new properties.

```js
const initialState = {
  students: []
}
const students = (state = initialState, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case 'ALL_STUDENTS':
      return {
        ...state,
        students: [...action.payload.map(student => {
          return {someprop: '', student}
        })]
      }
          
    default:
      return state;
  }
}

var newStudents = {
  type: 'ALL_STUDENTS',
  payload: [{id: "1", name: "Anie"},{id: "2", name: "John"}]
}

let state = students(undefined, newStudents);
console.log(state)
```

Comment: Not sure why you dont just use `[]` as initial state but if you already have students in that array you also need to spread those `...state.students`  so it should be like this https://jsfiddle.net/Lg0wyt9u/2497/

Comment: Nenad I have initial state[] because this is where I fetch from json

Comment: State students should be empty, because this is my first fetch json

Comment: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined and payload is unresolved btw

Comment: Last question, how can someprop: '' take current state value. For example if current state is 3, and I add someprop: '' it will changed. I don't want that

Comment: I assumed you have already data ready on reducer part. If you have just array as initial state you can just use this https://jsfiddle.net/Lg0wyt9u/2501/. What do you mean if current state is 3?

Comment: Can you please my last question?

Comment: I am not sure what are you asking, could you provide example of that scenario.

Comment: Let say someprop has value of 3. How can I pass student prop but remain that current value(3)